# Aggregation query is not showing output in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, aggregation-framework

I've following collection in my MongoDB database

**clat_output**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59fc6492421aa91e3e71d753"),
"output" : [ 
    {
        "time" : "100",
        "clat" : "127"
    }, 
    {
        "time" : "254",
        "clat" : "294"
    }, 
    {
        "time" : "354",
        "clat" : "437"
    }
    ...
    ...
]
}
```

I want to retrieve **clat_output** with a condition that **time** in **clat_output** should be in between a given range.

For example

I want to fetch **clat_output** having `_id = ObjectId("59fc6492421aa91e3e71d753")` with given time interval as `1` to `300`

So it should give following output

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59fc6492421aa91e3e71d753"),
"output" : [ 
    {
        "time" : "100",
        "clat" : "127"
    }, 
    {
        "time" : "254",
        "clat" : "294"
    }
]
}
```

When I run the following query in mongodb console then it's giving me desired result.

```
db.clat_output.aggregate({
  '$match' : {"_id" : ObjectId("59fc6492421aa91e3e71d753")}}, {
    '$addFields' : {
      'output' : {
        '$filter' : {
            'input' : '$output',
            'as' : 'result',
            'cond' : { 
                '$and' : [
                  {'$gte' : ['$$result.time', '1']},
                  {'$lte' : ['$$result.time', '300']}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

But when I converted the same aggregate query into raw query in laravel, it's showing `output` as empty array. Following is my query in laravel

```
public function clat_output($id, $start, $end) {
  $query = [
    ['$match' => ["_id" => $id]], [
       '$addFields' => [
          'output' => [
             '$filter' => ['input' => '$output', 'as' => 'result',
                'cond' => [
                   '$and' => [
                      ['$gte' => ['$$result.time', $start]],
                      ['$lte' => ['$$result.time', $end]]
                   ]
                ]
             ]
          ]
       ]
    ]
  ];

  $result = self::raw(function ($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate($query);
  });
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Though possibly not directly related, your data is flawed. You have `'time'` as a "string" and as such a value like `'5'` does not fall "between" the values of `'1'` and `'300'` since it begins with `'5'` and as a "string" that is not within the range. You actually want "numeric" values if you want to query for "numeric ranges". So you really should convert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your query is perfect. The only thing that I'm bit sceptical is about type mismatch of `$start` and `$end`. To validate you can use following code in mongo console.

```
function printSchema(obj) { 
  for(var key in obj) { 
    if(key === 'output') { 
       print('time',typeof obj[key][0]['time']); 
       break; 
    } 
  } 
}
var obj = db.clat_output.findOne();
printSchema(obj);
```

In php check data type of `$start` and `$end` by using following command

```
echo gettype($start),"\n";
echo gettype($end);
```

If there is mismatch in data type then you need to do type conversion.

Comment: Yes there was a type mismatch. time field was stored as string in database and I was comparing it with integer in php.